# Dart vm embed in C++ Application - Access Violoation

Tags: c++, dart

I'm trying to figure out how to embed dart in my own application. To get started I am trying to just print out the version number of Dart. 
Whenever I call Dart_VersionString() I get:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00002B992DDFA232 in DartEmbed.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00002B992DDFA232.
```

I've uploaded my example project to github.

https://github.com/mfrancis107/DartEmbed

I've tried it with both dart.exe in my path and copying dart.exe to x64\Debug directory.

Comment: One advise: Locate an example project and learn from that, it's unlikely you're doing something completely new. That said, you question (not problem) is off-topic, see the posting guidelines.